# Play Framework CryptoAES secret key

Tags: java, playframework

I was looking for some crypto functions in playframework, and in the documentation for encryptAES they say,"Encrypt a String with the AES encryption standard using the application secret".

Ok the function is looking like this but where can i found this secret key ?

Offical function code:

```
public static java.lang.String encryptAES(java.lang.String value)

    Encrypt a String with the AES encryption standard using the application secret
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It's placed in `conf/application.conf` file

In both - Play 1.x and Play 2.x its name is `application.secret`

You can also use custom key with method:

```
public static java.lang.String encryptAES(java.lang.String value,
                                          java.lang.String privateKey)
```

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2/play/libs/Crypto.html#encryptAES(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)